# From and From Named Graph in SPARQL

Tags: graph, sparql, rdf, named-graphs

I am getting a confusion related to `FROM` and `FROM NAMED` graphs in SPARQL. I did read the specifications relating to these two construct in the [SPARQL Specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#specifyingDataset). I just want to confirm my understanding.

Suppose an RDF Dataset is located at IRI `I`. `I` is made up of:

- a default graph `G`
- 3 named graphs `{(I1,G1), (I2,G2), (I3,G3)}`

Now, suppose I have a SPARQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM I
FROM I1
FROM NAMED I2
```

So if I understand, to evaluate this query, the SPARQL service may construct the active graph at the back, this active merge will contain:

- a default graph which is the merge of `I` and `I1`
- a named graph `I2`

Is this understanding right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `FROM`, `FROM NAMED` clauses describe the dataset to be queried. How that comes into being is not part of the SPARQL spec. There is a universe of graphs from which `I`, `I1`, and `I2` are taken.

You are correct that the dataset for the query will have a default graph which is the merge of `I` and `I1`, and also a named graph `I2`.

Whether those are taken from the underlying dataset is implementation dependent. It is a common thing to provide (the universe of graphs is the named graphs in the dataset) but it is also possible that the `I`, `I1`, and `I2` are taken from the web (the universe of graphs is the web).